# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors' on python anywhere

Tags: python, flask, flask-cors

To state from the get go this is no criticism of pythonanywhere,  but I want to run a script that used to work using the line:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
```

But I get the following error mesage:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'
```

Then tried to install in my version of python:

```
pip3.9 install Flask-Cors
```

The result was:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Looking in links: /usr/share/pip-wheels Requirement already
> satisfied: Flask-Cors in ./.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.0.10)
> Requirement already satisfied: Six in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask-Cors) (1.16.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.9 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask-Cors) (2.0.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->Flask-Cors)
> (2.0.1) Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->Flask-Cors)
> (2.0.1 ) Requirement already satisfied: click>=7.1.2 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->Flask-Cors)
> (7.1.2) Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->Flask-Cors)
> (3.0.1) Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in
> /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from
> Jinja2>=3.0->Flask>=0.9->Flask-C ors) (2.0.1) 15:33 ~$ pip show
> Flask-Cors
> Name: Flask-Cors Version: 3.0.10 Summary: A Flask extension adding a decorator for CORS support Home-page:
> https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors Author: Cory Dolphin
> Author-email: corydolphin@gmail.com License: MIT Location:
> /home/elksie5000/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages Requires: Six,
> Flask

What gives and how do I fix it?

Comment: Might you have two versions of Python installed, and are somehow installing Flask into one of them but then running your app via the other?  This is a very common problem.

Comment: Thank you for swift response. How do I check and how do I fix it, please?

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct environment when you install your packages. I know this is obvious, but maybe.

Comment: @elksie5000 - not so quick on my second response, lol.  Sorry about that.  You want to make sure that the `pip` that you use to install packages and the `python` binary that you use to run your code are coming from the same `bin` directory.  The easiest way to do that is to run `pip` using an absolute path, and then run your Python code at a command prompt as well, using an absolute path to the `python` binary.  If you're running inside an IDE, you need to make sure that the IDE is using the `python` binary that is in the same directory as the `pip` that you used to install packages.

Comment: ...a "best practice" is to always use a `virtualenv` to run your Python code, and to only install packages into a `virtualenv` and never into a base Python installation.  If you don't know about `virtualenvs`, it would be well worth your while to read about them (just google `python virtualenv`), and consider always using one.  In the end, using a `virtualenv` doesn't change the basic answer.  If you do use one, then it will contain a `bin` directory containing both a `pip` and a `python`, and you'd want to make sure those two binaries are coming from that same `bin` directory.

Comment: ...a common reason that the mismatch arises between `pip` and `python` versions is when installing packages via `pip` on the command line, but then running your code in an IDE.  Even if you do both in an IDE, it is not hard to end up in a situation where the IDE is doing the two operations within different Python environments.  No matter how you're running these binaries, you need to make sure that they match up.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try the following:

1. Go to your Bash Console in "Consoles" menu.
2. Open the bash control
3. Select your virtualenv:
   For example my virtualenv name is flaskapp, I would wirte "workon
   flaskapp" in the bash console.
4. Now type in your desired command
   pip3.9 install flask-cors in your case (try in lower case)
5. Make sure you are working in the same virtualenv and the same python version

(I think you want to make an API using cors maybe)

Comment: When you say "Make sure you are working in the same virtualenv", that's really the primary issue here.  For your answer to really address the problem, I think you need to elaborate on exactly what that means.  Also, although the OP should be using a virtualenv, they may not be, and judging by the output they posted, it appears that they are not doing so.  So maybe you should add a justification for why it is best to always use a virtualenv, and to only install package into a virtualenv and never into a base Python installation.

Comment: I'll take care next time